# Implementing field validation rules in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, invalid-data, regular-expression

I've found that ArcGIS offers validation of 2 basic constraints: field data type and if the value is required or not.

Is  there any way or AddIn to attach more complex validation rules?

I mean Min-Max values for numbers and dates, RegEx for text input, expression based validation for dependent fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do custom validation; if you are looking for a programmatic solution, the main ones you'll probably want to look at are [geodatabase extensions](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Geodatabase_extensions/0001000004p7000000/) and [editor extensions](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002nq000000).

Alternatively, if you have [ArcGIS Data Reviewer](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/data-reviewer/10.0/about) you can set up complex rules in that without programming. I am not sure if it can do everything you ask about though, and if I recall correctly it won't prevent people from entering bad data, only catch it when it is reviewed.

Answer (score 6):

You can add validation through the use of domains.
[A quick tour of attribute domains](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001s00000001000000.htm)

Comment: Yea, I've forgotten about range domains, but what about remaining more complex rules?